What are physical laws behind the vibrational energy transfer?
My orbital sander causes objects sitting on the surface where the force is applied to levitate slightly and rotate in the opposite direction to the spin of the sander. The harder I push down on the sander the faster the object would spin. Can some body explain this? What physival law is at work? And what bodies are important? The sander? The medium surface? Or the force receiver?
